# Nohup and & keep exiting

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, process, nohup

I am trying to run a process in the background, but every time I do, the terminal stands-by, then I press enter, and my process is exited.

I have tried:

- ```sh
  nohup ./binary &
  ```
- ```sh
  nohup bash -c "./binary" &
  ```
- ```sh
  nohup bash -c ./binary &
  ```

Nothing works; the shell always stands by. I have tried pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> after also but that does nothing when the shell is in standby. I have even tried exiting the terminal when the shell is in standby but when I log back in, I find the the process has stopped.

Comment: Dirty, but you could try kicking it off with a crontab.

Comment: Have you seen if there was an error message in the nohup file?
It should be in your current working directory.